# Is it possible to get current users authentication type Client Side?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sharepoint

I know you can get the current users Authentication type by HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.AuthenticationType in asp.net

Is there a way to achieve this with jquery etc?

Comment: Not sure about JQuery but you might be able to get such info sending it back from the server and saving it for later use.

Comment: Yea since I cant find a function to achieve this client side I was just going to get the information server side then just assign it to a global Boolean variable for my client side code to read.....

Answer (score 1):

**Primarily** I would get such info by sending it back from the server upon the first request and saving it for later use. **Other options are inferior but I will share it as it might spark some new ideas**:

1. Using JQuery to do an HTTP get for any page and extracting the AuthenticationType form the response HTML.
2. If you can add server side functionality. Using JQuery to do an HTTP get while having an endpoint on the server (like Web API). This end point can be independent form SharePoint as it will be the same user. You might be able to use the session info (from the cookie) if you are using form authentication.

Sorry for not being more helpful...